# How do I get Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 to display a burndown of individual epics?

Tags: pm-software, burn-charts

How do I create an Epic Burn-down chart in Visual Studio 2012? Can I do it in Urban Turtle?

I am new to managing software projects with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I've been using Jira Agile for the last two years and can easily create a burndown chart for each epic in Jira. I'm trying to replicate the same thing in Visual Studio 2012 and TFS.

Comment: Hi I haven't used visual studio for burndowns but the following link may be of interest to you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731579.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no per-epic burndown in TFS 2012 out-of-the-box. Something can be cobbled up relatively easy through the Warehouse if you have it available on your instance.

There is a [Report from InCycle](http://incyclesoftware.com/2014/08/scaling-agile-and-safe-metrics-with-tfs/), which can serve as a basis for your request. I've had to debug and fix some parts of it while at the last client where we used it. It's not perfect, but it will get you started.

Urban Turtle provides a progress bar on Epics on their version of the portfolio backlog, but as far as I can tell there is no per-epic-burndown built into that product either.